# Github Pages: Scripts from vendor directory are not getting loaded

Tags: git, github

I am trying to create a blog on `github` for learning. My repo is [hk-skit.github.io](https://github.com/hk-skit/hk-skit.github.io). I have added `angular` and `ui-router` scripts in my `vendor` directory. This is how I am including these in my `index.html`.

```
<script src="vendor/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

This is my directory structure:

[image]

On my local, things are working fine. But when I pushed my changes to github. I don't know why it's saying `404` for `angularjs` and `ui-router`. Here's the link: http://hk-skit.github.io/. Can anyone please help me on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem recently. Tried to rename the vendor folder (I used "deps") and it fixed the problem.

I don't know why this is happening, but it must be some new Jekyll version behavior.

**Update**

See answer from [kenmark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40625463/1634125) for the cause.

Answer (score 4):

here is the detailed cause of this problem: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3181-including-node-modules-and-vendors-folders-in-your-github-pages-site.htm

In short, simply create an empty `.nojekyll` file at the root of the gh-pages and you will be fine.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I changed the name of directory.

Comment: Do you have a link to your repo?